# Ormlite Query BuilderCondition

Tags: java, sql, orm, ormlite

i have a user form, the user specify the research criteria and i must apply them to get the right data from the database using ormlite :

```
  boolean set = false;

    QueryBuilder<Client, Integer> builder = clientsDao.queryBuilder();
    Where<Client, Integer> builderWhere = builder.where();

    if (!tfSearchName.getText().equals("")) {
        builderWhere.like("name", tfSearchName.getText().trim());
        builderWhere.and();
        set = true;
    }

    if (!tfSearchBalanceMin.getText().equals("")) {
        builderWhere.gt("balance", tfSearchBalanceMin);
        builderWhere.and();
        set = true;
    }

    if (!tfSearchBalanceMax.getText().equals("")) {
        builderWhere.lt("balance", tfSearchBalanceMax);
        set = true;
    }

    clientTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            set ? clientsDao.query(builderWhere.prepare())
                    : clientsDao.queryForAll()));
```

the problem with the query builder is there is always an `and` Clause in the end so that always throw an expection.

i want to know a good way to generate my sql statement using condition like i do in my code.

PS : sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `public Where<T, ID> and(int numClauses)`
For example:

```
int andClauses= 0; // number of clauses that should be connected with "and" operation

QueryBuilder<Client, Integer> builder = clientsDao.queryBuilder();
Where<Client, Integer> builderWhere = builder.where();

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tfSearchName.getText())) {
    builderWhere.like("name", tfSearchName.getText().trim());
    andClauses++;
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tfSearchBalanceMin.getText())) {
    builderWhere.gt("balance", tfSearchBalanceMin);
    andClauses++;
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tfSearchBalanceMax.getText())) {
    builderWhere.lt("balance", tfSearchBalanceMax);
    andClauses++;
}

clientTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            andClauses > 0 ? clientsDao.query(builderWhere.and(andClauses).prepare())
                    : clientsDao.queryForAll()));
```